# MS Access How do I query the results of another query

Tags: ms-access

I have an existing query (Query1) that returns 5 fields from a table. What I want to do is then have another query (Query2) that uses each record from one of the fields returned in Query1 to return fields from a different table. Both tables have a common field (Project). Query1 returns Project and 4 additional fields. For each record returned by Query1 I want to run Query2 based on the Project field. How do I design Query2?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since both tables share a common field (Project), you should be able to JOIN them in a single query without having to worry about subqueries. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Project = Table1.Project;
```

However, if Query1 is performing a specific operation to only return those 5 records, then you can just JOIN the results of Query1 to that other table. So your Query2 might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Query1 ON Table2.Project = Query1.Project;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me!! I just tried that but it displays all blanks. There are multiple items in table 2 that have the same project name. That isn't a problem is it?

Comment: Hi Scott. Can you post the query that you tried?

Comment: SELECT * FROM Tasks INNER JOIN Query1 ON Tasks.ProjectName = Query1.ProjectName;

Comment: Is ProjectName a text field? If so, make sure that the values in ProjectName are spelled/formatted the same, don't have extra spaces, etc., across both tables. Joining on text fields is generally not recommended because of these problems.